# A generic type to infer inner type from a generic?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, is it possible to do something like:

```
type Unwrap<T> = T extends T<infer U> ? U : never
```

I.e. infer the inner type from whatever subtyped generic you pass to it?

Comment: Afaik, nope, if you don't know the underlying generic type, For instance, you can extract the element type of the array but, you can't do it generically for every other generic type.

Comment: This isn't possible until something like [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) is implemented.  See the linked q/a for more info